# dynamically limit the maxLength in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, maxlength

The problem is that the text when typing goes beyond the bounds of EditText!
How to dynamically limit the maxLength, depending on the width(weight) of EditText?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/activity_1_cnstr_layout_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Text1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Text2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You want something similar to this -> `editText.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(20)`? This is Kotlin btw.

Comment: yes, but since the weight (width) of an Edittext will be different on different devices, the maxLenght parameter must be dynamic.